# How to convert RGB image to CIELAB using raster package in R?

Tags: r, r-raster, cielab

I have read an RGB image using the following code

```
library(raster)
#Load an image
logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plot(logo)
```

Now, I want to convert the RGB image to CIELAB image. How to do it using `raster` R package? I know `CRImage` Bioconductor package has a function to implement this (`convertRGBToLAB`). But I want to implement it using `raster` R package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `convertColor()` function:

```r
library(raster)
logo <- stack(system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster"))
plot(logo)
```

[image]

```r
new_vals <- values(logo) / 255
new_vals <- convertColor(new_vals, from = "sRGB", to = "Lab")
values(logo) <- new_vals
plot(logo)
```

[image]

Comment: I want to have average values of Lab. How to do that?

Comment: or like this: `x <- calc(logo, function(i) convertColor(i, "sRGB",  "Lab", scale.in=255))`. Perhaps followed by `mean(x)`, to get the average

Comment: @RobertHijmans `x <- calc(logo, function(i) convertColor(i, "sRGB",  "Lab", scale.in=255))` is taking long time to do the job.